# Adding icon from url in drawer item

Tags: android, icons, navigation-drawer

I am using [mikepenz material drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library for adding navigation drawer to my android project. How can I add icon to a particular drawer item (e.g. PrimaryDrawerItem) from a url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this piece of code:
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/CustomApplication.java

It's using Picasso or Glide to load the images. 
You just have to give your item a tag, and implement you loading like the example.